# Duplicate select2 item in the foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**Hello everyone, I'm returning the data with foreach from the dishes table in foods.
I bring the selected ids as selected, but this time it is copied until the selected one.**

```
 <select class="form-control select2 "  name="lunch" multiple="" data-select2-id="lunch{{$item->id}}"  aria-hidden="true">
<optgroup label="Öğle Yemeği" >
    @foreach ($foods as $food)
        @foreach ($item->dinner as $lunch)
            @if ($lunch != $food->id)
                @continue
            @else
                <option value="{{$food->id}}"  selected >{{$food->name}}</option>
                @break
            @endif
        @endforeach
        <option value="{{$food->id}}">{{$food->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</optgroup></select>
```

**My output of code like this: http://prntscr.com/110203m**
**How can i fix that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code repeats 2 times

```
<option value="{{$food->id}}"  selected >{{$food->name}}</option>
```

Try using this code

```html
<select class="form-control select2" name="lunch" multiple="" data-select2-id="lunch{{$item->id}}" aria-hidden="true">
    <optgroup label="Öğle Yemeği">
        @foreach ($foods as $food)
            <option value="{{$food->id}}" @if(in_array($food->id, $item->dinner)) selected @endif>{{$food->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Still "continue" can be used like this

```
@continue($lunch != $food->id)
```